# Chrome project - Where is Blink engine source code?

Tags: google-chrome, open-source, blink

Where is Chrome's Blink engine's source code located?

Comment: [Same question for Firefox and Gecko](/q/3268516)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** Active development appears to be occurring in [`third_party/blink`:](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/tree/master/third_party/blink)

---

It took 1 minute to find the [codebase](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink)  on the [blink homepage](http://www.chromium.org/blink).

---

Update regarding the 3gb size question in the comment.

You are probably looking at the whole master branch.
If you will look at the tree you will notice all the various contents of the master branch - lots of tests (layout,manual,performance etc.)

The actual [source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/).

Comment: Can you please tell me, Why it has largest size above `3 GB`?

Comment: I updated the answer to your comment.

Comment: This answer does not seem to apply anymore - the last update there is over one year old.

Comment: @phihag yes, they haven't updated the master branch in a while. Yet that is the official public codebase page.

Comment: Dev branches are not public?

Comment: I believe that codebase is no longer used. Active development appears to be occuring in "third_party/Webkit":  https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/master/third_party/WebKit

Comment: @timoxley thanks, updated the answer.

Comment: Apparently this may be moving in the future as well: (https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/topic/platform-architecture-dev/DKQn-SILZzo/discussion). Blink and Chromium are not really separable anymore.

Comment: `master` branch was replaced by `main`:
https://github.com/chromium/chromium/tree/main/third_party/blink

Comment: The _actual_ source code: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/third_party/blink/